# Can you identify this unknown sequence related to approximating circle area using unit squares?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, approximation

I am interested in finding out whether the following sequence has already been "discovered" or if it is worth submitting to OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences), since I can't find it on there or on wolframalpha. Here is the unknown sequence:

1, 4, 15, 56, 214, 833, 3276, 12985, 51720, 206379, 824547, ... [let's call this sequence #1]

This sequence arises when finding area approximations for quarter-circles with radius, r = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., using squares with side length of 1 unit. Specifically, I am counting how many unit squares fit inside the quarter-circle without crossing the edge of the circle PLUS all the "boundary" squares that cross the edge of the circle.

I found a separate sequence for the number of inside-the-circle unit squares that do not cross the edge of the circle and have identified it as [OEIS A156790](https://oeis.org/A156790):

0, 1, 8, 41, 183. 770. 3149. 12730. 51209, 205356, 822500, ... [let's call this sequence #2]

I found another sequence of the number of boundary unit squares that cross the edge of the circle, which is [OEIS A000225](https://oeis.org/A000225):

1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047, ... [let's call this sequence #3]

Adding the respective terms of sequences #2 and #3 together produces sequence #1.

I'm also curious what the explicit and/or recursive formulas would be for each of these sequences.

Edit: I have found the explicit formula for sequence #3 is 
a(1) = 1, 
a(n) = 2*(a(n-1)) + 1, for n >= 2.

My goal is to show that as the length of the radius approaches infinity, the average of sequences #1 and #2 divided by the radius-squared approaches pi/4.

Thanks for reading!

[image: Image showing quarter-circles from r=1 to 16, courtesy of desmos.]